# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

The following code fails to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int add2(const int& x)
{
    return x + 2;
}

template <typename T>
T add2T(T&& x) {
    return add2(std::forward<T>(x));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x = 0;

    cout << "Add 2" << endl;

    cout << add2(2) << endl;
    cout << add2(x) << endl;

    cout << "Add 2T" << endl;

    cout << add2T(10) << endl; 
    cout << add2T(x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With this message:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'T add2T(T&&) [with T = int&]':
main.cpp:26:20:   required from here
main.cpp:12:16: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'
     return add2(std::forward<T>(x));
            ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure why the compiler is trying to bind the non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue. The forward should decay into an lvalue reference anyways, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not related to forward.

In the call `add2T(x)`, the deduced template argument `T` is `int&`. (Only in this way can `T&&` be an lvalue reference type.) Thus the return type is also `int&`. However, the operand of `return` (namely `add2(std::forward<T>(x))`) is an rvalue that cannot be used to initialize `int&`. Hence the error message.

If you want to prevent the return type from becoming a reference type, you can apply `std::decay_t`:

```
template <typename T>
std::decay_t<T> add2T(T&& x)
```

Comment: Right! In hindsight it's much simpler than I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well i have an explanation but many might object it. intutionaly this might help you not to bother about it in future whie coding.
so my idea is that for a function (defined in a class)calling in c++ should not take a local variables, because for simple function the memory might hold a local variable as an argument but on using many more big functions the local variables will be terminated in somewhere middle .hence if we use constant arguments they are stored firmly in the program memory and hence we can use it as many times as we want .note that the functions i am talking about are only functions which we defined in a class. so this is my theory. you can check with the two examples i have given below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
class circle
 {
    private:
      double radius;
      int count;
    
public:
circle()
{
radius=1;   
}
circle(double radius)
{
    this->radius =radius;
}
double areas( const int &count)
{
    this->count=count;
    return count*3.1415*radius*radius;
    
}

  };
    using namespace std;
    int main()
 {
    circle alpha(3);

cout<<alpha.areas(3) ;
return 0;

}
```

now try taking away the ampercent sign in the function areas
p.s this is just my theory so if i am wrong please do tell me i am also a learner.